# Symfony2 validation of form field when type is set

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I've set a constraint on a class member variable using an annotation:

```
/* @Assert\Length(min="3") */
protected $password;
```

This constraint is added to a form built in a form class when I add a field corresponding to this variable without specifying its type:

```
$builder->add('password');
```

The type is guessed as "text".
But, I want the input type of this field to be "password".
But when I specify this type like this:

```
 $builder->add('password', 'password');
```

The constraint in the annotation is not added.

I know that I can add the constraint to the field in the form class:

```
$builder->add('password', 'password',  
 array('constraints' =>  new Assert\Length(array('min' => 3))))
```

Or I could use JavaScript to change the input type of the field from text to password.

But, I feel I should be able to inject the annotated constraints into the form whilst also specifying the type of the field. I imagine that this must be a common problem. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need set constraints in form type to validate your class. **First check your annotation, it must start with double "*"**.

To generate the form, you should add in your form type the method 'setDefaultOptions' with 'data_class' attribute:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{   
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'XXX\YourBundle\Entity\YourEntity',
        'id' => null
        ));     
}
```

Data will be validated with the constraints defined in your class